# Error in multiple xsi:schemaLocation

Tags: spring, sftp

I'm using spring integration and i need to include multiple xsi:schemaLocation.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">
```

I'm getting error while deploying that it could not load:

```
Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location   
 [spring-beans.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-  
context.xml]; nested exception is  
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration
 problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace 
 [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp]
  Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-
 beans.xml]
```

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I think maybe it is a dependency issue?  Currently checking my `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `spring-integration-sftp` to my `pom.xml` fixed this for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

2.0.3 is probably an old version, but that is what we are using for `spring-integration-core` so I kept it the same.